# Vehicles Data and Images API

Tags: data-request, api, cars

Are there any APIs available for vehicles? I am going to use this for Android Studio programming.

I want basically the vehicles, models, makes api. But if there are any apis which include more information it is better.

Comment: I know this is pretty old. Here is an opensource repo for all car data you need: https://github.com/abhionlyone/usa-car-models-data

Comment: @AbhilashReddy Can you post an answer about it, with a few example rows? Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

http://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/

The National Highway Traffic Safety Administration has a free API that provides VIN decoding and lists of Makes/Models/Manufacturers/Parts/etc.

XML, JSON, CSV

Here is an example to fetch all vehicle makes:

http://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/getallmakes?format=json

Answer (score 3):

There is a github repo with SQL data, but only up to 2013 (of course, you can extend it)

https://github.com/n8barr/automotive-model-year-data

> Automotive data including vehicle model, make, and year for database creation. Currently includes 7,268 model-years.

Sample data

```
2013, Volvo, C30
2013, Volvo, C70
2013, Volvo, S60
2013, Volvo, XC90
```

([my source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11208020/2327328))

Answer (score 0):

Databases.one - [Car Make Model Database](https://databases.one/) & [Cars Data API](https://databases.one/car-make-model-database-api/) is a modern web service, containing an extensive amount of over 260,000 rows separate detailed automotive technical specifications.
View Car Database Demo here: https://databases.one/cardatabase-demo-advanced/

Comment: That is not open data, it is a paid system.

Comment: Man is not looking for free.

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous sources of Vehicle data including images, for example, https://www.carimagery.com/ offers a database of images quite cheaply.

You can also get vehicle data (without images) from http://www.carqueryapi.com/

If you are specifically looking at the USA, then you can get Vehicle data, including the image from the number plate and state at http://www.vehicleregistrationapi.com/

Answer (score 0):

I've recently scraped similar data (car makes/models - over 2000 models in total) for my own project. Here is the link on github repo, where you can find json and sql script:

https://github.com/Savage3D/car-makes-models-data

Answer (score 0):

CarsXE now does vehicle specifications, history, market value, plate decoder, plate iage recognition, vehicle images, and vehicle identification.
docs found here- https://docs.carsxe.com/

Answer (score -1):

I suggest [car-database-api's database and documentation](https://www.car-database-api.com/vehicle-api-parameters). It's accurate, regularly updated and they have some cars which you cannot find in most databases on the net.

We checked the cars parameters and they were just like those you get from the manufacturers, aka - legitimate for use.

Answer (score -1):

The [Carsxe API](https://api.carsxe.com/) aggregates data from multiple vendors including the NHTSA into its API. They provide 4 APIs: vehicle specifications, history, market value and ownership cost.

The vehicle specifications API contains sample images of the vehicle you look up.

XML & JSON

Here's an example GET request you can make for a vehicle:

The API Documentation is [located here](http://api.carsxe.com/docs).

Here is an [example GET request](http://api.carsxe.com/specs?key=CarsXE_API_Key&year=2004&make=toyota&model=camry&include=selections,attributes,colors,photos).

Comment: They are quite nice, also the price, but they don't offer list of car makers and models per year